# MySQL join 3 table & aggregate each without subquery

Tags: sql, mysql, inner-join

There are 3 tables, `A`, `B`, `C`.

Table `A` has an `id` column, and `B` & `C` integer column which represents money and  `a_id` which reference id in table `A`.

Below is an example of table A, B, C

table A

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

table B

| id | a_id | money |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 1 | 2000 |
| 3 | 2 | 3500 |

tableC

| id | a_id | money |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 2 | 400 |

In this case, I wanna aggregate them like one of these.

| a_id | B_money_sum | C_money_sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | 100 |
| 2 | 3500 | 600 |

or

| a_id | money_sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2100 |
| 2 | 4100 |

I've tries this, but the result wasn't expected one.
(aggregation was based on cartesian product)

```sql
select a_id, sum(b.money) B_money_sum, sum(c.money) C_money_sum
from A
join B on A.id = B.a_id
join C on A.id = C.a_id
group by a_id
```

Isn't it possible only join, without subquery ?

Comment: Shouldn't the B_money_sum for a_id1 be 1000+2000=3000 ?

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't it possible only join, without subquery ?

No, because when there is more than one a_id (TableB and TableC) per id(TableA) that made a one-to-many join, which creates more rows (essentially, a duplication of rows, also known as "Relational Multiplication").

A common approach to fix that issue is to isolate the SUM() in a separate query , subquery

```
select a.id, B_money_sum , C_money_sum
from tableA a 
join (select a_id,sum(money) as B_money_sum
      from tableB
      group by a_id 
     ) b on a.id = b.a_id
join (select a_id,sum(money) as C_money_sum
      from tableC
      group by a_id 
     ) c on a.id = c.a_id  ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/coZvQsuT

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit trickier if table b has an id which c doesn't or vice versa. Let's take this case for example.

```
create table a (id int);
create table b (id int,a_id int,money int);
create table c (id int,a_id int,money int);
insert a values(1),(2),(3),(4);
insert b values(1,1,1000),(2,1,2000),(3,2,3500),(4,4,1000),(5,4,7000);
insert c values(1,1,100),(2,2,200),(3,2,400),(4,3,200),(5,3,600);
```

In this case, b has  id 4 while c has id 3. If we use an inner join, both id 3 and id 4 will have their data missing in the result set:

```
select a_id,sum_a,sum_b 
from
    (select a_id ,sum(money) sum_a
    from a
    join b on a.id=b.a_id
    group by a_id) tb
join
    (select a_id ,sum(money) sum_b
    from a
    join c on a.id=c.a_id
    group by a_id) tc
using(a_id)
;

+------+-------+-------+
| a_id | sum_a | sum_b |
+------+-------+-------+
|    1 |  3000 |   100 |
|    2 |  3500 |   600 |
+------+-------+-------+
```

However, if we use a one-sided outer join , we will still have some data missing on the other side.

```
select a_id,sum_a,sum_b 
from
    (select a_id ,sum(money) sum_a
    from a
    join b on a.id=b.a_id
    group by a_id) tb
left join
    (select a_id ,sum(money) sum_b
    from a
    join c on a.id=c.a_id
    group by a_id) tc
using(a_id)
;

+------+-------+-------+
| a_id | sum_a | sum_b |
+------+-------+-------+
|    1 |  3000 |   100 |
|    2 |  3500 |   600 |
|    4 |  8000 |  NULL |
+------+-------+-------+

select a_id,sum_a,sum_b 
from
    (select a_id ,sum(money) sum_a
    from a
    join b on a.id=b.a_id
    group by a_id) tb
right join
    (select a_id ,sum(money) sum_b
    from a
    join c on a.id=c.a_id
    group by a_id) tc
using(a_id)
;

+------+-------+-------+
| a_id | sum_a | sum_b |
+------+-------+-------+
|    1 |  3000 |   100 |
|    2 |  3500 |   600 |
|    3 |  NULL |   800 |
+------+-------+-------+
```

In order to bridge the gap for all sides, a full join is required. But since MySQL has yet to implement a full join, a UNION is called for to combine the two outer joins.

```
select * from
(select a_id,sum_a,sum_b 
from
    (select a_id ,sum(money) sum_a
    from a
    join b on a.id=b.a_id
    group by a_id) tb
left join
    (select a_id ,sum(money) sum_b
    from a
    join c on a.id=c.a_id
    group by a_id) tc
using(a_id)

UNION

select a_id,sum_a,sum_b 
from
    (select a_id ,sum(money) sum_a
    from a
    join b on a.id=b.a_id
    group by a_id) tb
right join
    (select a_id ,sum(money) sum_b
    from a
    join c on a.id=c.a_id
    group by a_id) tc
using(a_id)
) t_a_b
order by a_id
;

+------+-------+-------+
| a_id | sum_a | sum_b |
+------+-------+-------+
|    1 |  3000 |   100 |
|    2 |  3500 |   600 |
|    3 |  NULL |   800 |
|    4 |  8000 |  NULL |
+------+-------+-------+
```

Note: The outmost layer is required to use the ORDER BY clause, which is ineffective in UNION.